# Microdata + Schema.org validation error: "is not a know valid target"

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I try to markup my first page (a news website). The structure is like this:

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage>

<body>

<ul itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">  // main part

<li  itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle"> head line of an news1 </li>

<li  itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle"> head line of an news2 </li>

<li  itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle"> head line of an news3 </li>


</ul>
<div>

</body>
</html>
```

I got error with `itemprop="mainContentOfPage"` and `itemprop="itemListElement"` in [Google’s Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/structured-data/testing-tool/) because of

> is not a know valid target...

How can I solve this error?

Comment: (1) Note that you are missing a `"` in the first `itemtype`. (2) I don’t get the error you quote. Is this really the code you tested?

Answer (score 1):

The [`mainContentOfPage` property](http://schema.org/mainContentOfPage) cannot have an `ItemList` as value.

You probably want to use the [`mainEntity` property](http://schema.org/mainEntity) instead:

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<body>

  <ul itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Meaning: the `ItemList` item is the primary entity described in this `WebPage` item.